# Reflection C# Activator returning a null value

Tags: c#, reflection

Please I don't know what I am doing wrong, when I run this code, I get an exception: Value cannot be null.... When I run it in debug mode, I see that "calculatorInstance" variable is null. Please help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionWithLateBinding
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //load the current executing assembly
            Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            //load and instantiate the class dynamically at runtime - "Calculator class"
            Type calculatorType = executingAssembly.GetType("ReflectionWithLateBinding.Calculator");


            //Create an instance of the type --"Calculator class"
            object calculatorInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calculatorType);

            //Get the info of the method to be executed in the class
            MethodInfo sumArrayMethod = calculatorType.GetMethod("SumNumbers");

            object[] arrayParams = new object[2];

            arrayParams[0] = 5;
            arrayParams[1] = 8;
            int sum;
            sum = (int)sumArrayMethod.Invoke(calculatorInstance, arrayParams);

            Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}",  sum);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }



        public class Calculator
        {
            public int SumNumbers(int input1, int input2)
            {
                return input1 + input2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that `calculatorType` is not null?

Comment: @BrianPayne: I'm pretty sure that `calculatorType` *is* null, for the reasons given in my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure it's actually the `GetType` method which is returning `null` - because there's no type with the fully-qualified name `ReflectionWithLateBinding.Calculator`. Your `Calculator` class is nested within your `Program` class.

It's the call to `Activator.CreateInstance` which is throwing an exception, therefore the assignment to `calculatorInstance` is never made - it's not that the variable has a value of `null`, but rather that its declaration statement (which includes the initializer) never completes.

Options (don't do both!):

- Move the class so that it's *not* within the `Program` class (i.e. so it's declared directly in the namespace)
- Change your `GetType` call to `executingAssembly.GetType("ReflectionWithLateBinding.Program+Calculator")`

Comment: thanks alot, I moved Calculator class to a new class --outside Program class and now it works fine.